# .NET class error reporting - best practises

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling

Up until recently we used custom exceptions with an inbuilt errorcode to allow us to communicate errors or problems we don't like around our systems.

However, I was shown a different method where you have a publicly exposed collection of errors on each class that you populate if there was a problem. The calling method then calls myObject.IsValid (which sees if the error collection has any entries) to check if the call was successful. If it wasn't then you can iterate through the error collection to see what went wrong. As far as I understand this is how MVC works with the ModelState.

The claim was this was the more efficient approach to error communication as there is an overhead to throwing exceptions.

Is this claim true? Is there a third option that is even better than the above? What is the correct way to communicate errors and problems around a .NET application?

Comment: If an error is expected then it is not exceptional and should not be an exception. If something happens, that should not occur in normal operation the it is an exception. Not all errors are exceptions.

Comment: Thanks @Jodrell but the question still stands. If you are not throwing an exception to communicate an "expected" error what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: Whatever makes sense. How much, and what is the structure of the information you want to convey? What are the callers of your class expecting? I don't know of any defacto standard answer, I suspect any strawman suggested here will not meet universal acclaim.

Comment: Let's use the example of a simple Get method that returns data from the database. Some scenarios we might want to communicate are: no matching records, invalid search parameters, too many records matched, etc.